# Using time.time() in while loop causes function to be called twice

Tags: python, time, sleep

I created a function like this:

```
import time

def func(seconds):
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print(f'waited {seconds} seconds')
```

Now if I create a `while loop` like this and call `func(6)`, after 6 seconds, it will print `waited 6 seconds`:

```
start_time = time.time()
while time.time() - start_time < 5:
    func(6)

output:
waited 6 seconds
```

But if I create the same `while loop`, while calling `func(4)`, the script will wait 4 seconds, then print `waited 4 seconds` and after 4 seconds, it will print `waited 4 seconds` again!

```
start_time = time.time()

while time.time() - start_time < 5:
    func(4)

output:
waited 4 seconds
waited 4 seconds
```

Why does this happen?

I understand why `func(6)` behaves like that, but I expected that `func(4)` would be executed only once, thus printing `waited 4 seconds` only once.

Comment: When 4 seconds passed, the condition in while loop is still True and execution goes to `func(4)`.

Comment: *but I expected that func(4) would be executed only once,* Why, given that the condition in your while loop is that less than **5** seconds have elapsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens:

```
start_time = time.time()               # captures the time right now()
while time.time() - start_time < 5:    # 1.) checks the time right after last check
                                       # 3.) checks the time right after 6s passed
    func(6)                            # 2.) waits 6 seconds
                                       # 4.) done
```

When you use 4s:

```
start_time = time.time()               # captures the time right now()
while time.time() - start_time < 5:    # 1.) checks the time right after last check
                                       # 3.) checks the time right after 4s passed, still < 5
                                       #     (should be something along 4.00023 or so)
                                       # 5.) checks the time afte4 4+4s passed
    func(4)                            # 2.) waits 4 seconds
                                       # 4.) waits 4 more seconds
                                       # 6.) done
```

Subtracting times gives you a float:

```
import time

t = time.time()
time.sleep(1)           # guaranteed to wait at least 1s
print(time.time()-t)
```

Output:

```
1.00106596947
```

After `time.sleep(4)` you are still far away from 5 - which is the reason that it enters the loop twice.

Answer (score 2):

The while conditions checks if five seconds have passed. For `func(6)`, "6 seconds > 5 seconds", so the condition is met and it ends the while loop. When `func(4)` returns, the condition is "4 seconds > 5 seconds" is not True, so the while loop will iterate once more.

Answer (score 0):

The while condition (< 5) against the time-delta calculation would allow the while loop to enter again after 4 sec sleep, example the new time delta might be 4.0022xxx post the first 4 sec sleep, since the condition (4.0022xx < 5) is True, it will lead to second 4 sec sleep.